# How to normalize a SeriesGroupBy object in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df
user    amount
1       18.90
2       1092.22
2       293.01
1       40.00
```

And I want to divide each users amount by the norm of that users amount. So, the resulting dataframe would be

```
df
user    amount
1       0.4272
2       0.9658
2       0.2591
1       0.9042
```

Because the norm of user 1 is `norm1=sqrt(18.90^2+40^2)=44.24`, so we divide all user 1's amounts by `norm1`; and the norm of user 2 is `norm1=sqrt(1092.22^2+293.01^2)=1130.84` so we divide all of user 2's amounts by `norm2`.

So far, I have

```
 norms = df.groupby(['user'])['amount'].apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2))).values
 df.groupby(['user'])['amount'].divide(norms)
 >>> AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'divide' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

but this gives the error above. `norms` is indeed calculated correctly, but then I can't seem to use the `.divide()` method on each users amount.

How can I divide each users amount by the users amount norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.sum` function rather than going to groupby:

```
m = np.sqrt((df.set_index('user')['amount']**2).sum(level=0))
# sqrt(sum_of_amount_squares_based_on_user)
user
1      44.240366
2    1130.840125
Name: amount, dtype: float64
#map and divide 
df['new'] = df['amount']/df['user'].map(m)

  user   amount       new
0     1    18.90  0.427212
1     2  1092.22  0.965848
2     2   293.01  0.259108
3     1    40.00  0.904152
```

If you want `groupby` solution specifically you can do it this way :

```
df.assign(new=df['amount']**2).groupby('user').apply(
    lambda x : x['amount']/np.sqrt(x['new'].sum())
).reset_index()
```